# Error: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String' in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a search filter using a tableview with multiple sections and get the error 'Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String' on the line "cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.row].rowTitles". How do I fix this? The ultimate goal is to be able to display the rowTitles in sections of the tableview. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let dataArray = [(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2"]),
    (sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]),
    (sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["row 1"]),
    ]
    var searchArray = [(sectionTitle: String, rowTitles: [String])]()
    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchArray.count
        } else {
            return dataArray.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.row].rowTitles
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row].rowTitles
        }
        return cell!
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.dataArray.count
    }
}


extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchArray =  dataArray.filter({$0.sectionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())} )
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you should avoid force-unwrapping return cell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not use tuples as data source array. Use a struct.

There are many issues. Basically you are not considering the `section` information at all. You have to get the current section with `indexPath.section` and the current row with `indexPath.row`

Replace `numberOfRowsInSection` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchArray[section].rowTitles.count
    } else {
        return dataArray[section].rowTitles.count
    }
}
```

and `cellForRow` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath)
    if searching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.searchArray[indexPath.row].rowTitles is an array of Strings, not a String.

cell.textLabel.text is a String value, therefore you cannot assign the first to the latter.

I think you should use one of the strings inside rowTitles and assign that to the textLabel.text

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Because `cell?.textLabel?.text` expects `String` type whereas you are passing an array (`rowTitles`) of `Strings` to it.

Try to pass an string (based on your requirement) from your array (`rowTitles`) and it will be gone.

```
if searching {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.row].rowTitles[0]
} else {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row].rowTitles.first[1]
}
```